# Simplifying a check for path's non-existence in a shell script

Tags: shell, logic, boolean-logic

Whenever I want to check if a path exists in a shell environment, be it interactive or a script, I use 
`[ -L "${PATH_TO_CHECK}" ] || ( [ ! -L "${PATH_TO_CHECK}" ] && [ -e "${PATH_TO_CHECK}" ]`. A broken symbolic link is still an existing path to me. I'm trying to figure out how to check for the opposite, but I cannot figure anything simpler than `! ([ -L "${PATH_TO_CHECK}" ] || ( [ ! -L "${PATH_TO_CHECK}" ] && [ -e "${PATH_TO_CHECK}" ] )`. Is that check not reducible?

Answer (score 1):

[boolean-logic](/questions/tagged/boolean-logic) answer:

```
!(a || (!a && b))      
!a && !(!a && b)        # De Morgan's law
!a && (a || !b)         # De Morgan's law again
(!a && a) || (!a && !b) # Distributive law
!a && !b                # Complement law
```

(Bonus: apply De Morgan again to find that your original expression could be simplified to `a || b`)

[shell](/questions/tagged/shell) answer:

Just check that it's not an existing file and also not a link:

```
[ ! -e "$path" ] && [ ! -L "$path" ]
```